# Generate Parentheses in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I wanted to create a program that displays all valid arrangements for n couple of parentheses. The output should be an array sorted in ascending order of ASCII values. The following is the function that needs to be used.

```
fun solution(n: Array<String>): Array<String> {
    
}
```

I tried it using this, but cannot make it fit the above function,

```
fun balancedBracket(result: String, 
                         size: Int, 
                         open: Int, 
                         close: Int): Unit
    {
        if (close == size)
        {
            // When get the result of parentheses in given size
            println(result);
            return;
        }
        if (open < size)
        {
            // Add open parentheses
            this.balancedBracket(result + "(", 
                                 size, open + 1, close);
        }
        if (open > close)
        {
            // Add close parentheses
            this.balancedBracket(result + ")", 
                                 size, open, close + 1);
        }
    }
```

Input: n = 3
Output: ["((()))","(()())","(())()","()(())","()()()"]

Please help.

Comment: Could you provide an example what is the expected output for a sample input?

Comment: I have edited my post to show the input and expected output

Comment: If the input is only the number of parentheses then why `solution()` accepts an array of strings?

Comment: It is what was given

Answer (score 0):

```
fun printParentheses(size: Int) {

  fun inner(chars: String, size: Int, open: Int, close: Int) {
    if (close == size) {
      println(chars)
      return
    }
    if (open < size) {
      inner("$chars(", size, open + 1, close)
    }
    if (open > close) {
      inner("$chars)", size, open, close + 1)
    }
  }

  if (size > 0) {
    inner("", size, 0, 0)
  }
  
}

printParentheses(3)
```